# Auth0 login demo returns 400 on refresh and logs me out

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am working on adding Auth0 to my app, however, i am running into problems redirecting the user back to the page it was before the checkSession is called, since it currently takes me to the home page when a component loads due to the setSession method in auth0 redirecting me to the homepage (which gets called during login and renewSession)

anyways, the auth0 docs has a get started demo react app that i've tried to understand (perhaps they don't have that issue that i have?), and seems like a straight forward app. I downloaded the zip, unzipped the project, changed the values to the correct clientId, callback url etc.. then in the application settings in Auth0 dashboard, i added the allowed urls and callback urls. Login works, logout works, however after the user is logged in and i refresh the page i get a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400` error and it logs me out.

Is this a bug in the project, or am i doing something wrong? I pinpointed the problem to the checkSession method, for some reason the call fails.

the project uses auth0-js 9.0 but i've tried updating to 9.10 and the issue persists.

here's a link to the project

https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/tree/master/01-Login

Answer (score 0):

I do not have that issue with that React sample project. Refreshing the page on Chrome simply makes another checkSession call that succeeds. I would look into the console logs and network trace in your browser for more details. Also good idea to check your tenant logs for more details on why the login failed.